# merge objects for 3d printing

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, 3d-printing

I have several objects (see the attached picture) I want to merge, so that I finally get one uniformly mesh.

In the end I want to 3d print this object but the slicer software for the printer can´t handle these several loose objects. It preferes one single, clean mesh without non manifold edges.

I already tried using the Boolean modifier to join the objects but it ended in a mess with lots of non manifold edges.

[Here a link to the .blend file i created.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_x40ppckYQW56PAtJvNhDiu9Nth-EHP2)

Does someone have expierience with joining mulitiple objects into one single? Slowly I´m really annoyed from this problem and would be really pleased if someone could help me out with an solution for this.

[image: link]

Answer (score 1):

Typing Ctrl+J should work. It is a shortcut that joins meshes. If there are any modifiers that are not applied yet, apply them *then* hit Ctrl+J.

Comment: When I do this, the 3D printer interprets the intersection of objects as the XOR of the individual parts and the model becomes unstable at these intersections. When I add the boolean modifier 'merge', it works well, but I have too many objects to merge them all manually. Is there a way to merge (not join) all objects?